# codeigniter getting the values of a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Howe to get the value of a load view?

```
$test = $this->load->view('testing',$data);
```

How can I get the content of `$this->load->view('testing',$data);` an pass into a variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this.......

```
$test = $this->load->view('testing',$data,true);
```

entire view will return in `$test` string.

For reference please go through this link

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Check in the end of the page of the above link

Answer (score 1):

Add `TRUE` as the third parameter:

```
$test = $this->load->view('testing',$data, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $test = $this->load->view('testing',$data,true);
```